# Issue in Hibernate: Session is closed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session

I have this problem when I run the application I'm doing in Eclipse with Hibernate. Here I show to you the stacktrace and the main java class.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:332)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:126)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:647)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:102)
at vista.Principal$2.actionPerformed(Principal.java:124)
.
.
.
```

And here the part of the main class have the problem.

```
JList listaConsultas = new JList();
scroll.setViewportView(listaConsultas);

SessionFactory sesionfact1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session sesion1 = sesionfact1.openSession();
Transaction tr = sesion1.beginTransaction();

JButton btnConsultar = new JButton("CONSULTAR");
btnConsultar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        Query queryAcogida = sesion1.createQuery("SELECT s FROM rah_histo_saip_acogida s WHERE fecharealiza BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta")
            .setParameter("desde",fechaDesde)
            .setParameter("hasta", fechaHasta);

        List<RahHistoSaipAcogida> listaAcogida = queryAcogida.list();

        queryAcogida.setFetchSize(10);
        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        dlm.addElement("----ACOGIDA DEL PACIENTE----");
        for(RahHistoSaipAcogida acog: listaAcogida){
            dlm.addElement(acog.toString());    
            listaConsultas.setModel(dlm);
        }
    }
});

tr.commit();
sesion1.close();
btnConsultar.setBounds(281, 113, 120, 23);
contentPane.add(btnConsultar);
```

Comment: why do you have a transaction?  what are you committing?  Open and close your session in your `actionPerformed` method

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
```

is not called when you declare it.
The real workflow here is :

```
JList listaConsultas = new JList();
scroll.setViewportView(listaConsultas);

SessionFactory sesionfact1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session sesion1 = sesionfact1.openSession();
Transaction tr = sesion1.beginTransaction();

JButton btnConsultar = new JButton("CONSULTAR");
tr.commit();
sesion1.close();
btnConsultar.setBounds(281, 113, 120, 23);
contentPane.add(btnConsultar);
... and later ...
actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
```

So when your action is performed, the transaction is closed and the session too.
You should add your session action in the action performed method, like this :

```
JList listaConsultas = new JList();
scroll.setViewportView(listaConsultas);

SessionFactory sesionfact1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

JButton btnConsultar = new JButton("CONSULTAR");
btnConsultar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Session sesion1 = sesionfact1.openSession();
        Transaction tr = sesion1.beginTransaction();

        Query queryAcogida = sesion1.createQuery("SELECT s FROM rah_histo_saip_acogida s WHERE fecharealiza BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta")
            .setParameter("desde",fechaDesde)
            .setParameter("hasta", fechaHasta);

        List<RahHistoSaipAcogida> listaAcogida = queryAcogida.list();

        queryAcogida.setFetchSize(10);
        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        dlm.addElement("----ACOGIDA DEL PACIENTE----");
        for(RahHistoSaipAcogida acog: listaAcogida){
            dlm.addElement(acog.toString());    
            listaConsultas.setModel(dlm);
        }
        tr.commit();
        sesion1.close();
    }
});

btnConsultar.setBounds(281, 113, 120, 23);
contentPane.add(btnConsultar);
```